# Why bitnami Fluentd daemonsets dont generate logs as standard output?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, elastic-stack, bitnami, fluentd

I have deployed the Bitnami EFK helm chart on the K8s cluster.
**https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/fluentd**

All pod runs fine but Fluentd not showing any logs. I don't know if I have something missing in the config. However, the cluster is restricted, and don't know if that makes any difference. I deployed the same EFK on the unrestricted cluster with the same configuration and works totally fine.

```
kkot@ltp-str-00-0085:~/logging-int$ kk get pod
NAME                                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
elasticsearch-elasticsearch-coordinating-only-5f5656cdd5-9d4lj   1/1     Running   0          6h34m
elasticsearch-elasticsearch-coordinating-only-5f5656cdd5-h6lbd   1/1     Running   0          6h34m
elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data-0                               1/1     Running   0          6h34m
elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data-1                               1/1     Running   0          6h34m
elasticsearch-elasticsearch-master-0                             1/1     Running   0          6h34m
elasticsearch-elasticsearch-master-1                             1/1     Running   0          6h34m
fluentd-0                                                        1/1     Running   0          6h10m
fluentd-4glgs                                                    1/1     Running   2          6h10m
fluentd-59tzz                                                    1/1     Running   0          5h43m
fluentd-b8bc8                                                    1/1     Running   2          6h10m
fluentd-qfdcs                                                    1/1     Running   2          6h10m
fluentd-sf2hk                                                    1/1     Running   2          6h10m
fluentd-trvwx                                                    1/1     Running   0          95s
fluentd-tzqw8                                                    1/1     Running   2          6h10m
kibana-656d55f94d-8qf8f                                          1/1     Running   0          6h28m



kkot@ltp-str-00-0085:~/logging-int$ kk logs fluentd-qfdcs
```

Error Log:

```
2021-02-24 10:52:15 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "{\"log\":\"2021-02-24 10:52:13 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: \\"{\\\\"log\\\\":\\\\"
```

Has anyone faced the same issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please share what configuration is your forwarder using?

In the latest version of the chart (3.6.2) it will use the following by default:

```
  configMapFiles:
    fluentd.conf: |
      # Ignore fluentd own events
      <match fluent.**>
        @type null
      </match>
      @include fluentd-inputs.conf
      @include fluentd-output.conf
      {{- if .Values.metrics.enabled }}
      @include metrics.conf
      {{- end }}
    fluentd-inputs.conf: |
      # HTTP input for the liveness and readiness probes
      <source>
        @type http
        port 9880
      </source>
      # Get the logs from the containers running in the node
      <source>
        @type tail
        path /var/log/containers/*.log
        # exclude Fluentd logs
        exclude_path /var/log/containers/*fluentd*.log
        pos_file /opt/bitnami/fluentd/logs/buffers/fluentd-docker.pos
        tag kubernetes.*
        read_from_head true
        <parse>
          @type json
        </parse>
      </source>
      # enrich with kubernetes metadata
      <filter kubernetes.**>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
      </filter>
```

By the error log you shared:

```
2021-02-24 10:52:15 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "{\"log\":\"2021-02-24 10:52:13 +0000 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: \\"{\\\\"log\\\\":\\\\"
```

I notice two things:

- The fluentd pods seem to be collecting their own logs, which shouldn't be happening because of:

  > ```
  >    # exclude Fluentd logs
  >    exclude_path /var/log/containers/*fluentd*.log
  > ```
- The JSON logs are not being parsed although it is configured:

  > ```
  >     <parse>
  >        @type json
  >     </parse>
  > ```

Maybe you have omitted the configMapFiles in your `values.yaml`?

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for the feedback. I was providing config files externally but I used directly from Values.yaml and now I am able to get the logs but from 1970.01.01.

Comment: Replying to your other question, looks like there is an error parsing the timestamp for that log.
When fluentd doesn't find a timestamp, it will indeed use 1970.01.01.
To fix that, you could replace your input pattern to look similar to:
`
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_key timestamp
          time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N %Z

        </pattern>
`
Replacing time_key with the field where the time will be extracted and `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N %Z` to match your time format.

Comment: with this format I am able to see correct date.. THANKS. <parse>
        @type json
         time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 3.6.2 of fluentd and I have used the default ConfigMapFiles for forwarder and aggregator from values.yaml. After so many trials and errors I am able to see some logs but unfortunately since the year **1970.01.01** and of course in kibana I see logstash logs from 1970.01.01

```
kkot@ltp-str-00-0085:~/logging-int$  kubectl logs -l "app.kubernetes.io/component=aggregator"
```

**1970-01-01** 00:33:41.267229471 +0000 kubernetes.var.log.containers.payscan-56f94ddbcd-5fgqz_sgkb-r200-test_payscan-6a123dce39ade96b45ac156b69ea08f1bbc63382840782937dbeee8978d0f4dc.log: {"log":"\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:?]\n","stream":"stdout","docker":{"container_id":"6a123dce39ade96b45ac156b69ea08f1bbc63382840782937dbeee8978d0f4dc"},"kubernetes":{"container_name":"payscan","namespace_name":"sgkb-r200-test")

If I EXEC in of the fluentd container then DATE seems OK to me.

```
kkot@ltp-str-00-0085:~/logging-int$ kk exec -it fluentd-9kdp4 -- bash
root@fluentd-9kdp4:/opt/bitnami/fluentd# date
Mon Mar  1 07:20:20 UTC 2021
```

**Is there a way to fix this strange date error?**
Update: Answer

```
<parse>
  @type json
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
</parse>
```